# What is apercibido?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones, palabras-raras

Today I looked for the word **desapercibido** in the RAE and found the following:

> desapercibido, da.
>
> 1. adj. No apercibido.

Now, I know what desapercibido means, but then I was curious about the exact meaning of apercibido. So I looked for apercibido in the RAE and guess what:

> Aviso
>
> La palabra apercibido no está en el Diccionario.

All this came from a site that said that saying desapercibido for something that is inconspicuous was incorrect and that **inadvertido** should be used!!

Very confusing. Does someone have the exact meaning of apercibido? Since the RAE doesn't provide one.

Comment: btw. I do agree that REA should have better search and find all the forms of the word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You couldn't find *apercibido* in RAE, because it's participle of verb [*apercibir*.](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=apercibir)

As for *desapercibido* vs *inadvertido*. *Desapercibido* is most commonly used as for something that was not noted (possibly just because it was not important enough to anyone). *Inadvertido* in contrast means something that was not foreseen.

Very common usage is *pasar desapercibido*, meaning *to go/pass unnoticed*.

Comment: +1 Nice! Thanks!! Didn't think of that... But why inadvertido should be used instead or desapercibido?

Comment: This makes a lot of sense when we break down the word: desapercibido -> apercibir -> percibir = perceive.  Making desapercibido being unperceived (roughly).  Un-noticed makes perfect sense.